# best practice to deliver over 50 blendshapes over local wifi ( UNITY / Mirror )

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, wifi, unity3d-mirror

I'm pretty new to network coding and I'm wondering what would be the best practice to exchange over 50 blendshape (float) values over local wifi connection, with preferably 2 different builds in unity. One for desktop one for mobile. So, as I have somewhat delved in this problem, I have noticed that the unity's mirror is mostly efficient in delivering multiplayer functionalities within a same build. That's totally ok too, if it's a must. But my problem lies in the scenery where I can establish a connection, but I cannot make a decent use of the network capabilities, and hence I'm here asking for an advice.

TLDR;

50 blendshapes / shapekeys in Float
60 fps runtime

- from mobile build to desktop over wifi
  Unity / mirror

best practice?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I used mirrors Telepathy UDP server and sent data over bytearray :)